# clear the cache of Jenkins job

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am calling a python script from the job project> settings> build> run shell (bash).
The file I want to open in the script is not up to date, and Jenkins always remembers the old file I deleted in the script and Jenkins opens it.

I also found that the python delete command was not executed.
It looks like Jenkins is caching the initial file tree.

How can I always refer to the latest file tree?
Is there a command to clear the cache?
And how do I run the python delete command (`os.remove(latest_sc_file)`)?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Python3 --version is: "`python3 --version`
# Python3 --version is: Python 3.5.2
echo "Python3 full-path is: "`which python3`
# Python3 full-path is: /usr/bin/python3

git checkout submit

# Check for added / changed files
for file in `git diff --name-only HEAD..origin/submit`
do
    # echo $file
    name=`echo $file | sed -r 's/.*submission_(.*).csv/\1/'`
    echo "name: "$name

    # pull submission.csv, test.csv
    git pull origin submit:submit

    # Start scoring
    /home/kei/.pyenv/shims/python3 ./src/go/score.py $name linux > ./src/go/score.log 2>&1

done
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause has been found.
It was because Jenkins wasn't caching it, but was downloading a remote file every time I git pulled it.
Therefore, I will withdraw this question.